# Check if input is empty on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords, undefined

I am trying to check whether or not the password field on a form has been filled in on submission on a form but it always returns as "undefined" so the code I'm trying to run when the form is submitted never runs.

The username field seems to work fine though.

Here's my code...

```
$("#form1").find("input[type=submit]").click( function() {
    if($(".username").val() != "" && $(".password").val() != "") {
        console.log("Success")
    } else {
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you provide the html?

Comment: I would not use a class selector for the username or password. Use an ID.

Comment: the selectors are ok? the username input box has a class `username` and the password input box has a class `password`? Or are those the id's, and should it be `#password` and `#username`?

Comment: try alert($(".password").val()) and see if it is coming , but my guess is you have not provided the class names to the input fields

Answer (score 1):

Something must be wrong with your html since it seems to work:

```
<form id="form1" method="post">
    <input type="text" class="username">
    <input type="text" class="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

[See live example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rN2RJ/)

I have a feeling that you might be confusing classes that are selected with a "." with id's that are selected with a "#", but if I don't see your html, I'm just guessing.